# Proper usage of multiple `cy.request`s inside a custom cypress command

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to reset the database state using a custom cy command that runs on a `beforeEach` hook:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("resetDB", () => {
    // Purge users and sessions
    cy.request("DELETE", Cypress.config("dynamoDbAdmin") + "tables/Users/all")
    cy.request("DELETE", Cypress.config("dynamoDbAdmin") + "tables/Sessions/all")
    cy.request("PUT", Cypress.config("mock")
})

//example usage
beforeEach(()=> {
    cy.resetDB()
})
```

This inconsistently fails with:

CypressError: Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise. The command that returned the promise was:

```bash
mvp-cypress-1  | The command that returned the promise was:
mvp-cypress-1  | 
mvp-cypress-1  |   > `cy.request()`
mvp-cypress-1  | 
mvp-cypress-1  | The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:
mvp-cypress-1  | 
mvp-cypress-1  |   > `cy.resetDB()`
mvp-cypress-1  | 
mvp-cypress-1  | Because Cypress commands are already promise-like, you don't need to wrap them or return your own promise.
mvp-cypress-1  | 
mvp-cypress-1  | Cypress will resolve your command with whatever the final Cypress command yields.
mvp-cypress-1  | 
mvp-cypress-1  | The reason this is an error instead of a warning is because Cypress internally queues commands serially whereas Promises execute as soon as they are invoked. Attempting to reconcile this would prevent Cypress from ever resolving.
```

I've experimented with all 99 techniques, such as employing `cy.wrap`, incorporating `.then` in the chain, ensuring the request is properly `return`ed, and more - but to no effect.